# Review Site > Need common post template or plugin for product thumbnail, details and description

Tags: templates, wordpress, plugins, post

I'm working on a site in which each post will be dedicated to a single product review. I'd like to have a consistent look for each review so that the product image or cover art is at the top left. To the right of the product image, I'd like a listing of items (author, sales page, product cost, etc).

Below these two, I'd like a summary description area, spanning both columns. I don't want to use tables if possible (the summary description will have a clear:both setting perhaps).

Finally, I'd like to specify a list of "Related Products" in the right sidebar area. I'd like to be able to simply flag a category that contains the "related products" and have the top products in the category shown (as thumbnail images) as well as links to the product page.

Should I create a post template for this or do you have recommendations for a plugin that will work better and database each product separately (rather than placing it all in the post markup)?

TIA :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these specific requirements on the stuff you want displayed - yes, you need a post template. WordPress 3.0 introduces custom post types which might ease you in the work, but all the data you insert should be displayed appropriately => product post template OR a lot of html in you post, formatting all that stuff. The least doesn't have any flexibility and if hardly a solution to the problem.